Large NTFS disks are causing Ubuntu 24.04 to hang during I/O operations
I noticed that while performing I/O operations on large NTFS disks, (say 1TB, 2TB), Ubuntu is freezing. SSH and Ping do not return anything from remote PC, and this PC does not respond to keyboard, mouse. The clock in display is stopped as well. This situation requires a forcefull poweroff.
Here is the PC configuration:



Name
Description




CPU
Intel Core i9-13900K


GPU
MSI GeForce RTX 3090 VENTUS 3X 24G


RAM
Corsair DDR5-5600MHz 64GB (2 x 32GB)


SSD
CORSAIR MP600 PRO Low Profile Series 500 GB


HDD
Seagate BarraCuda 7200rpm 3.5" 2TB


Motherboard
ASUS PRIME Z790-P-CSM


Monitor
LG 27UL500-W Monitor Display, 27 inches, 4K



Below is the OS information:
ravi@asus:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

ravi@asus:~$ uname -a
Linux asus 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ravi@asus:~$ ntfs-3g --version
ntfs-3g 2022.10.3 integrated FUSE 28

Below are the journalctl logs
$ journalctl -b -1 | grep -i error
May 23 09:31:55 asus kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
May 23 09:31:56 asus kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dsfield-184)
May 23 09:31:56 asus kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230628/dswload2-477)
May 23 09:31:56 asus kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230628/psparse-529)
May 23 09:31:56 asus kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dsfield-184)
May 23 09:31:57 asus systemd[1]: Started apport-autoreport.path - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch).
May 23 09:31:57 asus systemd[1]: Started apport-autoreport.timer - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (timer based).
May 23 09:31:57 asus systemd[1]: Starting apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
May 23 09:31:57 asus whoopsie-upload-all[1493]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
May 23 09:31:57 asus systemd[1]: Failed to start apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
May 23 09:31:58 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1656]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
May 23 09:31:58 asus pipewire[1649]: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.jackaudio.service was not provided by any .service files
May 23 09:31:58 asus wireplumber[1652]: Failed to get percentage from UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner
May 23 09:31:59 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1797]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
May 23 09:31:59 asus gnome-session[1807]: gnome-session-binary[1807]: WARNING: Could not check if unit gnome-session-x11@gnome-login.target is active: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.systemd1: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
May 23 09:31:59 asus gnome-session-binary[1807]: WARNING: Could not check if unit gnome-session-x11@gnome-login.target is active: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.systemd1: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
May 23 09:32:00 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1883]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
May 23 09:32:00 asus kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
May 23 09:32:00 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1933]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
May 23 09:32:00 asus gsd-sharing[1897]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
May 23 09:32:00 asus gnome-shell[1826]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
May 23 09:32:02 asus gsd-sharing[1897]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
May 23 09:32:04 asus pipewire[2217]: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.jackaudio.service was not provided by any .service files
May 23 09:32:05 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2342]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
May 23 09:32:06 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2431]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
May 23 09:32:07 asus gnome-session[2579]: gnome-session-binary[2579]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2610: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such process
May 23 09:32:07 asus gnome-session-binary[2579]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2610: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such process
May 23 09:32:07 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2699]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
May 23 09:32:07 asus kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
May 23 09:32:07 asus gnome-shell[2611]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
May 23 09:32:07 asus tracker-miner-fs-3[3146]: (tracker-extract-3:3146): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 09:32:07.765: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
May 23 09:32:08 asus gsd-sharing[1897]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing: The connection is closed
May 23 09:32:08 asus gsd-print-notif[1903]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications: The connection is closed
May 23 09:32:08 asus gsd-smartcard[1910]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard: The connection is closed
May 23 09:32:08 asus gsd-housekeepin[1935]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping: The connection is closed
May 23 09:32:08 asus gsd-datetime[1913]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime: The connection is closed
May 23 09:32:08 asus unknown[1921]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy: The connection is closed
May 23 09:32:08 asus kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
May 23 09:32:08 asus kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
May 23 09:32:18 asus gvfsd-network[3401]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: Failed to spawn the underlying wsdd daemon.
May 23 09:32:18 asus gvfsd-network[3401]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: mountpoint for org.gtk.vfs.mountpoint_wsdd already running
May 23 09:32:19 asus gvfsd-network[3401]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: mountpoint for org.gtk.vfs.mountpoint_wsdd already running
May 23 09:32:23 asus google-chrome.desktop[3504]: [3497:3497:0523/093223.791747:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not part of the idle inhibition specification: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/idle-inhibit-spec/latest/
May 23 10:31:57 asus systemd[1]: Starting apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
May 23 10:31:57 asus whoopsie-upload-all[4334]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
May 23 10:31:57 asus systemd[1]: Failed to start apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
May 23 13:32:05 asus systemd[1]: Starting apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
May 23 13:32:05 asus whoopsie-upload-all[4867]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
May 23 13:32:05 asus systemd[1]: Failed to start apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
May 23 16:32:15 asus systemd[1]: Starting apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
May 23 16:32:15 asus whoopsie-upload-all[5394]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
May 23 16:32:15 asus systemd[1]: Failed to start apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
May 23 19:32:34 asus systemd[1]: Starting apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
May 23 19:32:34 asus whoopsie-upload-all[5906]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
May 23 19:32:34 asus systemd[1]: Failed to start apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
May 23 20:30:09 asus google-chrome.desktop[3504]: [3497:3497:0523/203009.804382:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(127)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
May 23 20:55:45 asus google-chrome.desktop[3504]: [6082:18:0523/205545.191363:ERROR:sdp_offer_answer.cc(3827)] Transceiver not found based on m-line index (INVALID_PARAMETER)
May 23 21:04:36 asus google-chrome.desktop[3504]: [3497:3497:0523/210436.931583:ERROR:extension_host.cc(458)] Received EventAck for extension aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb for an unknown event.
May 23 21:08:12 asus udisksd[1155]: Error probing device: Error sending ATA command IDENTIFY DEVICE to '/dev/sdb': Unexpected sense data returned:
                                     (g-io-error-quark, 0)
May 23 21:08:38 asus gvfsd-network[3401]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: Failed to spawn the underlying wsdd daemon.

I can not find the culprit other than suspicious Error probing device: Error sending ATA command IDENTIFY DEVICE to ... line. I verified both of my NTFS disks on Windows (disk scanning and defragmentation) and they work all good on the same PC. However, Ubuntu is freezing with them.
How to fix it?

So you're dual-booting with Windows (if not then the first suggestion had to be don't use NTFS) and the big HDD has, perhaps, a shared data partition? Have you disabled the Windows Fast Startup "feature? It's a must when dual-booting. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

What else do you have in the logs, around the suspicious messages? Don't grep for 'error' – look through it.

As @ChanganAuto implies, anything that leaves the Windows partition "dirty" prevents writing to it (unless forced). Not only Fast Startup, but Quick Boot and Windows Hibernation should be disabled if writing to a Windows partition.

@ChanganAuto Thank you very much always. This is indeed a dual-boot system with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 OS. The two large disks are external/portable HDDs for data backup, with 1TB and 2TB capacity. Formatting them as NTFS allows to plug them into both OS whenever needed. Next, I will turn off the Windows Fast Startup feature.

@grawity_u1686 Other than 'error', the following lines asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=7c336, Correct links count -> 1. and asus kernel: ntfs3: 12841 callbacks suppressed shows ntfs activity (of correcting data?). The journalctl -b -1 is really long, so I split and it to Pastebin: (part 1 of 2) journalctl -b -1.log and (part 2 of 2) journalctl -b -1.log. Do you find anything? Thank you so much.

@DrMoishePippik I understand. It is a dual-boot system with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 OS. The two large disks are external/portable HDDs for data backup, with 1TB and 2TB capacity. Do I need to disable Quick Boot and Windows Hibernation on Windows 11 while working with external NTFS disks?

@ravi, only the Windows system drive matters. In particular, if hiberfil.sys, pagefil.sys or swapfil.sys are on that drive, that indicates writing to that drive is an issue. Other drives should be writable.

@ChanganAuto , grawity_u1686 and DrMoishe Pippik: Thank you for your suggestions. Windows Fast Startup, and Hibernation has been disabled but the problem persists! Any suggestions to debug it further?
